# PWA: Site cannot be installed: the page does not work offline

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

I don't understand the reason, why Chrome shows, the application wouldn't work offline. It needs an internet connection but it's loading everything dynamically as JSON. Why isn't it allowed to fetch data in a progressive web app.
You can check it at https://testapp.jasmich.de/

Comment: I could not really get your complaint. Do you want the app not to require internet connection, like offline-mode or so?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot or more logs to what exactly the error was? Once I was able to render your application, I went offline and was able to see it again. Not sure what your issue is. Your Lighthouse report looks pretty decent too.

Comment: I don't understand why Google forces you to support offline/caching if it's actually an app needing an internet connection.